# What is 3-channel Thermal Image

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm searching about Thermal Image and got some research paper about object detection from Thermal Image. I see a [paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPRW_2019/papers/PBVS/Ghose_Pedestrian_Detection_in_Thermal_Images_Using_Saliency_Maps_CVPRW_2019_paper.pdf) where they worked with 3-channel Thermal image. They Extarct it to 1-channel image and 2-channel Image. But it is not clear to me how they are doing it.

So My question is what is 3-channel Thermal Image?

and How they extract it and again marge it?

Comment: They are taking three channels out of a multispectral dataset. Probably not the best idea in practice, as multispectral cameras are expensive.

Comment: @YvesDaoust actually i know that thermal image is only black white. Then how it becomes 3-channel? It makes confusion for me.

Comment: "i know that thermal image is only black white": not necessarily. Lookup multispectral camera.